# Kivy Touch - Raspbian Stretch 26.07

Tags: kivy, raspbian

after a long time trying it by myself i think it is the right time to ask for help.
my setup:

- raspberry pi 3 B+
- official 7' raspberry Touchscreen
- Kivy installed
- Raspbian Stretch 26-07 image

I have problem to activate the touchscreen while using kivy on the newest raspbian strech image.

normally it worked with a clean installed raspbian stretch image, clean installed kivy and after running a kivy demo there is an folder named '.kivy' in /home/pi.

in this folder in need to configure the touchinputs with following commands:

```
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

but i cant find this folder and cause of that i cant use the touchscreen with kivy.

I followed step 1, 2 and 3:
[kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-rpi.html)

when i run whereis kivy:

whereis .kivy :

```
/usr/bin/. /usr/sbin/. /usr/lib/. /bin/. /sbin/. /etc/.fstab /etc/. /etc/.java /lib/. /usr/games/. /usr/local/bin/. /usr/local/sbin/. /usr/local/etc/. /usr/local/lib/. /usr/local/games/. /usr/include/. /usr/local/. /usr/share/. /opt/sonic-pi/bin/. /opt/vc/bin/. /usr/man/man3/. /usr/man/man1/. /usr/share/man/ko/. /usr/share/man/sv/. /usr/share/man/man2/. /usr/share/man/sl/. /usr/share/man/it/. /usr/share/man/man6/. /usr/share/man/man7/. /usr/share/man/tr/. /usr/share/man/pl/. /usr/share/man/hu/. /usr/share/man/cs/. /usr/share/man/pt_BR/. /usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8/. /usr/share/man/nl/. /usr/share/man/pt/. /usr/share/man/man5/. /usr/share/man/da/. /usr/share/man/man8/. /usr/share/man/de/. /usr/share/man/id/. /usr/share/man/gl/. /usr/share/man/vi/. /usr/share/man/ja/. /usr/share/man/es/. /usr/share/man/man3/. /usr/share/man/fr/. /usr/share/man/zh_CN/. /usr/share/man/man1/. /usr/share/man/fi/. /usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1/. /usr/share/man/ru/. /usr/share/man/zh_TW/. /usr/share/man/man4/. /usr/share/info/. /usr/src/sense-hat/.
```

Do you have some ideas for me how I can fixed that ?

Answer (score 0):

after days for searching, I found finally the folder:
/root/.kivy

for the future when the folder change places:
if you start the kivy script from another computer with Putty (ssh), you can see in the first line after starting the script the path to this folder.

> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-07-26_59.txt

best regards

Danjin